# Get one(pitch) euler angle between two orientations (quaternions)

Tags: ros, transform, jointstate, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to get the angle between 2 quaternions (as euler angle), but the angle always needs to be from q1 to q2 (not the shortest angle).
But since there are two ways to get an angle, I need to find the one I need. The following code works, but I'm looking for a nicer solution.

```
// calculate difference
ori_diff = q1.inverse() * q1;

//just use the pitch part
ori_diff.setValue(0., ori_diff.y(), 0., ori_diff.w());
ori_diff.normalize();

//get euler angle
tf::Matrix3x3 m;
m.setRotation(ori_diff);

tfScalar r1, r2, p1, p2, y1, y2;
m.getRPY(r1, p1, y1, 1);
m.getRPY(r2, p2, y2, 2);

if (        r1 == 0 && y1 == 0 ) {
  euler_angle = p1;
} else if ( r2 == 0 && y2 == 0) {
  euler_angle = p2;
} else {
  ROS_ERROR( ... );
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192006/get-one(pitch)-euler-angle-between-two-orientations-(quaternions)/) by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2014-09-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the angles.h from the [angles package](http://wiki.ros.org/angles) one can found a lot of functions.

---

Originally posted by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) with karma: 179 on 2018-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0